# Couldn't generate the response in latin1 encoding style - in gsoap C++

Tags: c++, encoding, gsoap, iso-8859-1

I am using gsoap 2.8.31 and developed a stand alone server.

Need to produce the output in `latin-1` encoding. Now by default the response in UTF-8 encoding.

Included the below methods to set the omode to `latin-1` in my code,

```
soap_set_omode(soap,SOAP_ENC_LATIN);
soap_omode(soap,SOAP_ENC_LATIN);
```

But even after including these, could not see any changes reflected in response to `latin-1` encoding.

Please let me know if I have missed any methods to set the encoding style and charset to `latin-1`.

Many Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The input mode flag `SOAP_ENC_LATIN` is automatically set by the XML parser when detecting ISO-8859-1 encoded XML.  There is no mechanism to force ISO-8859-1 output, but you could replace the XML declaration as follows:

```
soap->prolog = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"latin1\"?>\n";
```

Make sure to avoid using any Unicode characters in the XML payload to send, which will end up encoded in UTF-8.